# BOOST_FOREACH with ptr_vector of noncopyable object

Tags: boost-foreach

I have the following:

```
class X : public boost::noncopyable
{...};

class Y 
{
   public:
      const boost::ptr_vector<X>& getXs() const;
   private:
      boost::ptr_vector<X> m_xs;
}

int main()
{
   Y y1;
   //...

   const boost::ptr_vector<X>& mx = y1.getXx();

   BOOST_FOREACH(boost::ptr_vector<X>::value_type x, mx)
   {
       // do something with x!
   }
}
```

It compiles but it doesn't link! It says that `implicit default copy constructor for X` is needed by the BOOST_FOREACH.

How can I iterate over the pointers to X only... no copy contructor, using `BOOST_FOREACH`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using references in `BOOST_FOREACH()`, .i.e.

```
BOOST_FOREACH(boost::ptr_vector<X>::value_type &x, mx)
{
    // do something with x!
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work. The problem seems to be that `BOOST_FOREACH(boost::ptr_vector<X>::value_type &x, mx)` requires the copy constructor. I don't knwo whie.

Comment: Hm, what I wrote didn't really make sense, sorry about that. Try either `const boost::ptr_vector<X> &mx = ...` and then `BOOST_FOREACH(const boost::ptr_vector<X>::iterator::value_type &x, mx)` or try those without both `const`'s.